# как остановить событие прокрутки после завершения

Tags: javascript

Столкнулся с проблемы чтобы при скролле вниз на странице появляються элементы, после того как они уже появились скрипт досихпор работает, при каждом скроле он продолжает добавлять класс active как можно его остановить.
js:

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
$(".advantage-options").each(function() {
            var pos = $(this).offset().top;
            var winTop = $(window).scrollTop();
            if (pos < winTop + 780) {
                var i = 0;
                var interval = setInterval(function() {
                    var cont = document.getElementsByClassName("adv-item");
                    if (i < cont.length) {
                        cont[i].className += " active";
                        i++;
                    } else {
                        clearInterval(interval);
                    }
                }, 120);
            }
        });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Выполните проверку:

```
if(cont[i].className.indexOf("active")==-1){

   cont[i].className += " active";

}
```

Или используйте jQuery, раз уж все равно используете:

```
$(".adv-item").addClass("active");
```

Этот же вариант с jQuery, но с номером элемента:

```
$(".adv-item").eq(i).addClass("active");
```